# IFTTT segmentation fault

Tags: linux, command, segmentation-fault

I'm doing an assignment for school using getop with ocelot, I have to count words and count the substrings in the document. I have the word counting working but I was not able to do the substring, I can only get to read/display what substring the user wants, that's what the program is about. Now, when I put for example on the commandline:

```
./hello -c -f substringToFind test.txt
```

it works but that's because the file test exists, if I say for example: `./hello -c -f hd test`

it would give me a segmentation fault. How can I read if it was a s. fault and display a message? ex:

```
if(segmentation fault){
printf("...");
exit(1)
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be better answered in [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com) than here. I'm also guessing you meant *getopt* instead of *getop*.

If I'm getting your problem correctly, you might want [to check for the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230062/whats-the-best-way-to-check-if-a-file-exists-in-c-cross-platform#230068) instead of the segmentation fault:

```
if( access( filename, F_OK ) != -1 ) {
    // file exists
} else {
    // file doesn't exist
}
```

Comment: I'll test it tomorrow, I have a test today, thank you.